# How to extract first n characters from a cell and copy it into a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I wanted to extract the first two words into one cell and the third one into another cell and they should be in a new worksheet. Example:

In Sheet1, Cell A1 'xxx-xx-xxx'

In Sheet2, it should be like this:

Cell A1: 'xxx-xx'
Cell A2: 'xxx'

How can I do this using VBA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA's "Split" method.

```
Sub SplitCell()

    getString = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value2
    splitString = Split(getString, "-")

    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = splitString(0) & "-" & splitString(1)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) = splitString(2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Two Out of Three

```
Sub TwoOutOfThree()

    Const cSheet1 As Variant = "Sheet1"   ' Source Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSheet2 As Variant = "Sheet2"   ' Target Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cCell As String = "A1"          ' Source/Target Cell Range
    Const cDel As String = "-"            ' Delimiter

    Dim vnt As Variant  ' Source Array

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet1)
        ' Split Source Cell Range into Source Array.
        vnt = Split(.Range(cCell), cDel)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet2)
        ' Write first two words to first cell.
        .Range(cCell) = vnt(0) & cDel & vnt(1)
        ' Write third word to second cell.
        .Range(cCell).Offset(0, 1) = vnt(2)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm :D

Thank you so much sir!